# I use CreateWindowExA to create window. Why my window header text is displayed as if it was in multibyte encoding?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have this program:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSA wnd_class = { 0 }; 
    wnd_class.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wnd_class.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wnd_class.lpszClassName = "actwnd";

    RegisterClassA(&wnd_class);

    HWND main_wnd = CreateWindowA(wnd_class.lpszClassName, "Program activation", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 640, 480, NULL, 0, wnd_class.hInstance, NULL);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the Window caption is displayed incorrectly:

[image]

It looks like for unknown for me reason, something still think this is unicode two byte encoding...

The file advanced saving options encoding set to single byte one - win 1251.

I want to use exactly ANSI versions and my window header contain only ANSI characters.

Comment: Any other reaction aside of unagrumented -1?

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: I don't know. I ask for possible reason of this. I tested it on two PCs and everywhere window header is like this

Comment: If you want help, please supply an SSCCE so that we can reproduce this. You should be able to supply a 20-30 line SSCCE. I don't know why you think there's something wrong with the header file.

Comment: I included full source of solution... Maybe it easer that making project by yourself. Solution is short enough regarding creating window. It created in ActivatioWindow.h line 104

Comment: Why can't you supply an SSCCE? A single file that can be pasted into an editor and compiled immediately. Should be around 20-30 lines. Offsite ZIPs are no good.

Comment: The window creation code looks fine. If I make and SSCCE from it, most likely it will work fine too. I think the problem in the project, so shared with project which is simple enough, if look only into ActivatioWindow.h

Comment: If you make an SSCCE, and it works fine, then you'll be able to isolate where the problem is. Would you prefer us to do that for you?

Comment: Wait, I will try to create SSCCE.

Comment: I included SSCCE. Create empty console application in vs and paste this code. For me the window with wrong header encoding still appears

Comment: Thank you for making that SSCCE. You did a good job there, and I appreciate that you responded positively to my prompting. The question is better now.

Comment: Thank you too for explaining me all this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your window procedure needs to call `DefWindowProcA`.

Comment: Thank you. Since it never gave me any errors, I though it fine with **DefWindowProc**...

Comment: No errors, because `DefWindowProc` doesn't receive parameters of character types. But character data does pass through a window procedure and has to be accessed by casts. So, it cannot be type checked.

Comment: Geez what is with all these people recently who are writing ANSI apps?

Comment: Oh huh... I noticed there are also ANSI versions of DispatchMessage and GetMessage. Looks like in my example they are "W" versions, but everything looks fine

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what the issues are with those. I suspect you should use the ANSI versions. If you really want to target ANSI, then you should configure your project to use MBCS rather than Unicode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `GetMessageW` converts the message to Unicode, then `DispatchMessageW` sees that the destination window is ANSI, so it converts the message to ANSI before dispatching. The important thing is that the encoding of `GetMessage` match that of `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`.